# Capacitor and resistor in parallel in output 19V laptop charger

Tags: power, adapter

I have been studying with my charger and I cannot figure out why it leak ac while also providing DC 19V. When I touch anode and cathod of the charger and checked it, there were no ac current flow. I want to reduce the current or make it safe to work. How can I do this ? Also giving capacitor of 25V and resistor in parallel does the job. But will it cause any problem in future ?

Thank you..

Comment: **ALL** mains power adapters will leak some AC current from the mains supply due to **capacitive coupling** in the circuit (mainly the class Y capacitor), this is normal and generally not an issue. *Also giving capacitor of 25V and resistor in parallel does the job* It is unclear what you mean, **draw the circuit**. Mention what the actual AC current is and explain **why** the current needs to be lower than that and **why** you think it is a problem.

Comment: Thank you, I meant that when I use capacitor and resistor to discharge it, connecting with anode and cathod of the charger. This also remove AC leakage.

Comment: *This also remove AC leakage* No it doesn't, it might terminate the AC leakage to ground if the supply is grounded. It is unclear what you're doing as you didn't include a schematic.

Comment: I thought if the output smoothing cap is damaged so I put another one and for ac, I did connect resistor. I think It's not good for my charger. What do you think ?

Comment: *I thought if the output smoothing cap is damaged* What made you conclude that? Did you **measure the output ripple, while the output is loaded, with an oscilloscope?** What ripple voltage did you get? Did you measure the capacitor's ESR? If you answer **no** to any of these questions you didn't have a good reason to replace the capacitor. Did you replace it with a **low ESR capacitor**? My feeling: you're doing things that you don't understand and that you should not be doing. But it is not my supply or laptop that will be damaged so do whatever you like.

Answer (score 2):

> *I cannot figure out why it leak ac while also providing DC 19V*

It likely leaks low levels of AC current in both DC output leads because the noise reduction circuit inside the charger has a Y capacitor from DC output to the live or neutral AC wires, This cuts down high frequency noise from the internal high=speed flyback transformer but, a side effect is that it leaks low level 50/60 Hz current to the output DC wires.

> *I want to reduce the current or make it safe to work*

It's not normally regarded as a problem and is safe but, you may have a faulty charger and maybe you should consider replacing it. If you can measure the AC current with a DVM, it should be around 1 mA to earth.

> *Also giving capacitor of 25V and resistor in parallel does the job.
> But will it cause any problem in future ?*

I think you are connecting them from the DC output to earth and if that works then it's likely that your charger isn't "dangerous" or faulty. However, check with a DVM on the AC range measuring current and see what you get - if it's around a milli amp then it's safe. If it's above 5 mA then there might be a problem: -

[image]

Table from [here](https://jmkengineering.com/electric-shock-human-body/).

Comment: Is it really safe ? I have two more of them. And all of them 19V and all leaks AC current.

Comment: But slight sensation or tingle sensation that feels low.

Comment: Get a DVM and measure the AC current to ground - compare with numbers in table column marked 60 Hz AC. At 50 Hz, the currents will be slightly lower.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have it now. I did check with multimeter and it shows random number and then goes to zero. lol

Comment: You probably had the DVM set to measure DC and not AC.

Comment: I have checked it, it's only 0.02 AC, but from tester It shows red signal. But first it shows more number then jump to .002 or .003 at some point.

Comment: I have digital multimeter.

Comment: I don't know what a red signal is and I don't understand the changing values you see. Does it remain steady at a number on AC? .002 mean 2 mA I estimate.

Comment: Yes, it is mA. It is constant after 1-2 seconds. I think it's normal since my other charger also leaks AC.

Comment: Then it is likely a good device and nothing to worry about. Of course if you bought it from a non-recognized source and is made by a non-specified manufacturer, then I can't say that it will be safe but, that's another story.